# RazorGenerator.MsBuild Setup - What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: msbuild, razorgenerator

The instructions on how to set up package RazorGenerator.MsBuild **(RGB)** to pre-compile my views are somewhat vague to me. I am running into a few issues that I can use some help with:

The instructions are found here: [Instructions](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20RazorGenerator.MsBuild)

What I've done so far, and what's happening...

1. I've installed the RGB to my web application from the NuGet command
   like with no errors (if I try this from the "Manage NuGet Packages"
   UI, and click the "Manage" button for the RGB, I get the following
   error: "RazorGenerator.MsBuld could not be installed because it is
   not compatible with any project in the solution.  The package
   doesn't target any framework" - this seems strage to me).
2. I receive no output in obj\CodeGen.

**Note: I have have "NuGet Package Restore" set to true, but that didn't seem to help with the automatic set up as specified in the instructions under heading "Enabling the target without NuGet Package restore" (e.g. target and  setting).**

I guess my questions is: How (and in what file(s)?/UI?) do I set the following in my web app as per the instructions to set up RGB?  Something tells me that these are not set up, nore can I find them in my solution or web application project files:

> a) Import the RazorGenerator.target file in your application
>
> ```
> <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\packages\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.1.5\tools\RazorGenerator.targets"/>
> ```
>
> b) Add a property to your project
>
> ```
> <PrecompileRazorFiles>true</PrecompileRazorFiles>"
> ```

#### EDIT:

Found out where to put the above settings - in my web app project file, only had to change RazorGenerator.MsBuild.1.5 to RazorGenerator.MsBuild.1.5.3.0 (my version).

Now Getting compiler errors on RGB-generated `.cs` files on the namespace created, for example, this is generated by the RGB version 1.5.3.0:

```
namespace GAFCOM.Web.Views.Simple.Roofing.Residential.Promotions.12_06_15_Better_Homes_And_Gardens
```

and produces the following compiler error:

```
Error   52  '{' expected
C:\TFS\GAF\Marketing\GAF.com\Dev-branch\GAFCOM\GAFCOM.Web\obj\CodeGen\Views\Simple\Roofing\Residential\Promotions\12_06_15_Better_Homes_And_Gardens\Better_Homes_Gardens.cshtml.cs
```

RGB version 1.5.0.0 generates this same namespace as:

namespace GAFCOM.Web.Views.Simple.Roofing.Residential.Promotions._12_06_15_Better_Homes_And_Gardens (note underscore before last namespace segment).

If I change the namespace to include the underscore (as above) in my current project, it compiles clean.

Any thougnts?

Comment: Looks like it was a bug in the MsBuild task (https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/workitem/106). I pushed a fix for it and have it up on http://www.myget.org/F/f6cb0207fba541b080113a51b38bceeb/

Do you think you could try the updated package and see if it addresses your issue? If so I'll push it to the NuGet gallery.

Comment: @Pranav - that goes for invalid chars like embedded dashes also e.g. my-dir.

Comment: Should be fixed in the latest package. Grab it from nuget.org

Comment: @Pranav I'll pull it down and give it a try, ty.